# What is flag weight?

Tags: support, flagging

I opened up my profile this morning and saw my flag weight was 160.

What is flag weight, and how does that effect me?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight

Comment: @Nyuszika7H Posts can't be marked as duplicates of each other across different sites.

Comment: @Anna I know, I posted that comment manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag weight is a measure of how reliable your content flags are. When you flag a post or an answer for moderator attention, we get the option to dismiss the flag as valid or invalid. "Valid" increases your flag weight, "invalid" lowers it. Your flags will be given a lower priority (i.e. appear further down the list of mod flags) if you have a low flag weight.

More details and the official FAQ entry [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight).

Comment: Danke! (text padding.)